# Can cell number for vba be given using two variables

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4, AS variant

VAR1 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "J").Value 
VAR2 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "K").Value 
VAR3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "L").Value 
VAR4 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "M").Value

=sheet1.range(VAR1,VAR2).COPY
=Sheet3.range(VAR2,VAR4).Pastespecial
```

for the above i have given cell numbers in Var1 Var2...Var4

Is it possible to define a cell location using two variables,

```
Var1=B
Var2=5
```

and somehow combine them to get B5,I want to do this in the macro itself.

Comment: Two small remarks:
1. Instead of `rng1.Copy` and `rng2.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` you can simply use `rng2.Value = rng1.Value`
2. Instead of letters for columns you can also just use numbers. Don't know if this is applicable in your situation, but most often this is more convenient in VBA than using the letters...

Answer (score 3):

You can. VBA allows you to concatenate strings in a range assignment. In this case it looks like:

```
Sub test()
Dim Var1 As Variant
Dim Var2 As Variant
Dim rng As Excel.Range

Var1 = "B"
Var2 = "5"
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Var1 & Var2)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. FWIW I'd use strings rather than variants - not that it matters, just to be clearer to the coder a string will result

Comment: @brettdj, agreed. I started to write a comment about the OP using the `Dim x, y, z as Variant` structure and that unlike what they might think it would declare them all as ... `Variants`. Would be a more worthwhile comment if they were declared as `Strings`.